# How to populate combobox 2 based on combobox 1 in excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel,

I have two columns one contains city names and another contains employee name. multiple employee can be in each city.

```
column 1         column 2

Mumbai           Raj Sharma
New delhi        Ankita
Kolkata          Parth
Mumbai           Rahul
Mumbai           Aadesh
Kolkata          Anis
Chennai          M. swami
```

In user form1 I have two combo boxes.

In combobox 1 I want to populate unique city names (Mumbai, New Delhi, Kolkata, Chennai) from column 1 and in combobox 2 I want all the respective employees.

```
combobox1        combobox2

Mumbai           Raj Sharma
Mumbai           Rahul
Mumbai           Aadesh
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: while posting my question I edited both columns and result columns but they are mixed up when posted. please have a look like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next code, please. The `Sub`can be called during the userForm `Initialize` event (I will show you how), or from a button `Click` event. It uses `cbCity` and `cbPeople` combo boxes. Please, **change their names with the one you use**:

1. the code able to load 'cbCity` combo:

```
Private Sub testPopulateCombo1()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, LastRow As Long, arr As Variant, El As Variant, j As Long
  Dim arrC As Variant, i As Long, k As Long, boolFound As Boolean
 
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here yor sheet
   LastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
   
   arr = sh.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value
   ReDim arrC(UBound(arr) - 1)
   'Fill the city names:
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        For Each El In arrC
            If El = "" Then Exit For
            If El = arr(i, 1) Then boolFound = True: Exit For
        Next
        If Not boolFound Then arrC(k) = arr(i, 1): k = k + 1
        boolFound = False
   Next i
   ReDim Preserve arrC(k - 1)
   Me.cbCity.List = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrC)
   Me.cbCity.ListIndex = 0 'load the first item in the combo
End Sub
```

2. It can be called from the UserForm `Initialize` event, in this simple way:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  testPopulateCombo1
End Sub
```

3. In order to populate `cbPeople` combo, when `cvCity` changes its value, you must use its `Change` event. Double click on the combo, choose from the top right side `Change` and paste the next code (over it):

```
Private Sub cbCity_Change()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, arrP As Variant, i As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
   arrP = sh.Range("A2:B" & sh.Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
   Me.cbPeople.Clear
   For i = 1 To UBound(arrP)
    If arrP(i, 1) = Me.cbCity.Value Then
        Me.cbPeople.AddItem arrP(i, 2)
    End If
   Next
   If Me.cbPeople.ListCount > 0 Then Me.cbPeople.ListIndex = 0
End Sub
```

If you do not use the combo names I used, please **adapt they changing with yours**!

During the `Initialize` event the first combo is loaded and its first element (`.ListIndex = 0`) will be shown. Then, after each change in `cbCity` combo, the appropriate people names will be load in `cbPeople`.

Please, test it and send some feedback. But, if possible, not tomorrow or even later...

Comment: @Kadar Khan: Did you find time to test the above code?

Comment: @Kadar Khan: Still alive?

Comment: it didn't work. i did not want two columns in cbPeople combobox. i wanted only the respective employee names in cbPeople.

Comment: @Kadar Khan: What do you mean by "the respective employee names"? All the names from the second column? If yes, I can easily adapt it.

Comment: @Kadar Khan: Are you sure that you can explain what you need? Would you like ,when you select a city in the  first combo box , the corresponding people of it to be loaded in the second one?  Will we wait for other two days in order to receive an answer? You placed an enumeration of name for three times Mumbai...

Comment: Sorry bro for late replies. As i have mentioned in question in cbPeople i want names of people who belongs to the same city. Like if i choose Mumbai only those employees  should appear which belongs to Mumbai. Not all the employees.

Comment: @Kadar Khan:  Your way of asking questions is not the most appropriate, I would say.  I asked "Would you like ,when you select a city in the first combo box , the corresponding people of it to be loaded in the second one?". Is the answer at this question yes? I do not want working until I am not sure I understood what you want.

Comment: yes brother that is what i want. i think the barrier is language. i could not explain properly.

Comment: @Kadar Khan: OK. I will adapt the answer code, even if this is different than what you asked in your question...

Comment: @Kadar Khan: Glad I (finally) could help!